# C# generic bounds

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a abstract dto class，I want to write a batch class to deal the derived dto：

dto:

```
public abstract class Command
    {
        private string TraceNo { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ObjectDumper.Dump(this);
        }
    }
```

derived dto:

```
 public class UserLoginDirectlyCommand : Command
    {
        public List<string>? LoginUserId { get; set; }
        public int ReserveCount { get; set; }
    }
```

interface:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<in T> where T : Command
{
    void Handler(T command, byte[] attachment);
}
```

concrete handler:

```
public class LoginDirectlyCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<UserLoginDirectlyCommand>
{
    public void Handler(UserLoginDirectlyCommand command, byte[] attachment)
    {
    }
}
```

I want to get a dictionary with key is command id and value is concrete handler:

```
public static Dictionary<int, T> GetCommandHandler<T, TC>() where TC : Command where T : ICommandHandler<TC>
    {
       List<ICommandHandler<Command>> list;
       var dic = new Dictionary<int, T>();
       dic[2] = new LoginDirectlyCommandHandler();

       return dic;
    }
```

but the statement `dic[2] = new LoginDirectlyCommandHandler();` cannot compile：`Cannot convert source type 'LoginDirectlyCommandHandler' to target type 'T'`

Could anyone tell me how to pass the compile? thx!

Comment: My compiler tell me it can't be implicitly converted, so I try explicitly converting it: `dic[2] = (T)(ICommandHandler<Command>)new LoginDirectlyCommandHandler();`

Comment: Your design is flawed. The caller of `GetCommandHandler` expects a dictionary with `T`s, which is a type that the caller specifies. But your method returns a dictionary with a `LoginDirectlyCommandHandler` in it, which is not necessarily what the caller wants.

Comment: But judging from your comment, `GetCommandHandler` is supposed to return different types of `ICommandHandler`s. Leaving aside the fact that it currently is declared to only return one type, `T`, the caller is also unable to do anything with such a dictionary in a typesafe way, because the caller does not know the specific type of command that each handler in the dictionary handles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... so now we have this method:

```
 public static Dictionary<int, T> GetCommandHandler<T, TC>() where TC : Command where T : ICommandHandler<TC>
    {
        List<ICommandHandler<Command>> list;
        var dic = new Dictionary<int, T>();
        dic[2] = new LoginDirectlyCommandHandler();

        return dic;
    }
```

How would you call that method?

Like this?

> GetCommandHandler<*Something that extends ICommandHandler*, *something
> that extends Command*>()...

So now when the dictionary is instantiated it will instatiate it with that *concrete* type.

Thus when you do the assignment to LoginDirectlyCommandHandler it cannot guarantee that the concrete types provided will be compatible with the assignment taking place. The concrete type you provided could be anything (as long as they subclass Command and ICommandHandler respectively). Thus there is no guarantee that those types will be compatible with your assignment of LoginDirectlyCommandHandler.